# VCL styles : during final Builder compilation

Tags: delphi, finalbuilder

To define the VCL styles for my application at runtime, I found the following link [DELPHI VCL STYLES](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/category/vcl-styles/).
Is there also an option to set the VCL style for my appliaction during the compilation process using finalbuilder tools ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I somehow have more than one profile on SO. Here's the screenshot

[image: Resource compiler options]